Total question count changing
When I refresh the page, sometimes the total number of questions changes. I know it might be a duplicate but I can't seem to find any discussion of this problem anywhere.



I can reproduce this. Caching... it must be caching.

@TravisJ https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Why should it remain the same? Aren't questions being added and removed all the time?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk - Yes, they are. That was also my first thought. But not to the degree this varies, and not within those time frames. It goes back and forth within fractions of a minute over values which would take most of a day. The batch scripts run at night, so its not the server causing this thrashing effect. It must be caching. Seriously though, it is caching's fault, maybe... probably. This is probably the result of multiple nodes in a server farm load balancing where their start time holds some sort of historical count versus what they observe during their uptime.

It looks like the /questions page flips randomly between 3 different values (currently: 24,203,451; 24,200,409; and 24,207,997), which all differ significantly from the number of questions reported by a search for all non-deleted questions (currently: 24,195,005).

Related: Clicking on the last page of the "Recently Active Questions" gives "Page not found" error and Bug with changing pages. All of these are symptoms of the same caching issue (We're hitting multiple instances each of which think the number of questions is different).
